# HTTP request/ response issue

Tags: ajax, json, angularjs, http-headers, httprequest

I am sending a GET request from AngularJS, and I get the correct output, but when I check [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) I see that the Response header is coming from Catch. What is causing this?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `cache: false` option from wherever you are doing the `$http` call?

Comment: no it is not working...

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to this problem is to append a unique param to url. Like this:

```
$http({
   url: 'http://...',
   params: { 'something': new Date().getTime() }
});
```